# Get all distinct rows from each column from a table along with their count

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL statement which creates a table from many joins for which I need to get all the distinct columns along with their count, this is going to be used for sending information to a front end filter (this filter will have the distinct value and how many times it is in the table). One way I thought of doing it would be to simply get the distinct value from each of the columns individually, but this would be very taxing because the table is a made up of many other tables and joined together which means it could be very taxing for the system to execute each of these columns individually, recreating the table each time.

One way to do it as I said before would be to get the distinct value from each of the columns an execute these statements separately, and later combine the results, like so:

In the "Customers" table I am getting the unique rows in each column as well as the count for each column.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in

```
SELECT CustomerName , COUNT(CustomerName) FROM [Customers] GROUP BY CustomerName;
SELECT ContactName  , COUNT(ContactName) FROM [Customers] GROUP BY ContactName;
SELECT Address  , COUNT(Address) FROM [Customers] GROUP BY Address; 
SELECT PostalCode   , COUNT(PostalCode) FROM [Customers] GROUP BY PostalCode;   
SELECT Country  , COUNT(Country) FROM [Customers] GROUP BY Country; 
SELECT City , COUNT(City) FROM [Customers] GROUP BY City;
```

TLDR;
Pretending my table is "Customers" as above, but is a very expensive table to call multiple times and remake, is there anyway to do what I did above in one statement, I.E to reduce the amount of times I have to join multiple other tables to recreate the same table.

```
Select a.col1, a.col2, b.col1, c.col2
FROM a, b left join c
where a.4 = c.4  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        I need to get the distinct values for `a.col1, a.col2, b.col1, c.col2` along with their count from the result set of this query.
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by Create Table, do you create an actual MySQL table or you mean the result set of your query?

Also the provided w3schools link is just an example select

Comment: I added to the post an example of what kind of result set I am working with. Basically I want to the results of an existing SQL query and get the distinct values for each of the columns along with the count.

Comment: How your end result should look alike.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent enough version of MariaDB/MySQL you can use with WITH clause to create such a table, you can check the docs here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

If you require the table to be updated and not be created every time (you make the query that is) you can take a look at MySQL's MEMORY tables:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

This way you can create an in-memory table and fill it with the required data and updated it when needed.